# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio - Scripting

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.3128 and need to use "script table as" to generate drop and create script for my tables. I have 107 tables in my database.

If I select all my tables the generated script omits foreign key drops, and omits pk and fk key create scripts. Excluding one of the tables (any) yields the expected result including fk and pk scripts in the generated SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I'd say he wants to know how to script all tables including the fk and pk in the script.

Comment: I think he's looking for the MySql function where you can export tables/databases/etc in a neat and slick import script.

Comment: @TechieJoe: MySQL?  The question's text and tags don't reflect any connection to MySQL.

Comment: There is no reason to put this on Hold, it was a viable and clear question that was answered.

Comment: @J03gan - There is a similar functionality in MySql but is much much easier to get the final product than in SQL Server.

Comment: @TechieJoe difference is without a consistent Interface to MySQL, its all command line.  SSMS gives you the flexibility without really knowing the command lines.  The same scripting functionality that MySQL has, MSSQL has as well, just the command structure is way complicated.

Comment: @GoldBishop - My point exactly.

Answer (score 6):

1) Select Database

[image]

2) Right Click, select Task -> Generate Scripts

[image]

3) Choose Objects > Select whether you want the whole database or a subset of Tables, Views, SProc, Functions

[image]

4) Set Scripting Options -> Select whether "Publish to Web Service" or "Save scripts to file-system".  In the next area, click "Advanced"

[image]

5) Advanced Scripting Options, here is your focus.  You will want to do the "Table/View Options" section and pick True or False, as your needs require.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Generate Script works fine, but doesn't add DROP statements to the generated SQL script. I have created a new dummy table in my database. When selecting all tables I have the same problem (foreign keys are omitted) when not selecting the dummy table the script contains everything!

Comment: Drop is in the Advanced Window.  Its the one noted as "Script DROP and CREATE", it is a drop selection of how to perform.

Comment: Thanks I have found it seeing the picture above. Thanks again.

Comment: Side note: in SQL2008r2 version the Check statement was an actual command.  With 2012, the Drop & Create statements are run thru `sp_executesql`.  From what i can find, there is no way to remove this behavior.  So you will either need to deal with it or manually remove the behavior.  It sucks, but have to deal with it.